# How do I include python.h into c properly on Windows

Tags: python, c, windows, libraries

When I try and include python.h file in a c file I get the following error

code:

```
#include <Python.h>

static PyObject *method_fputs(PyObject *self, PyObject *args) {
    char *str, *filename = NULL;
    int bytes_copied = -1;

    /* Parse arguments */
    if(!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "ss", &str, &filename)) {
        return NULL;
    }

    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "w");
    bytes_copied = fputs(str, fp);
    fclose(fp);

    return PyLong_FromLong(bytes_copied);
}
```

Error:

```
FAILED: CMakeFiles/Practice.dir/main.c.obj 
C:\...\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\CLion\ch-0\213.5744.254\bin\mingw\bin\gcc.exe   -g -std=gnu99 -MD -MT CMakeFiles/Practice.dir/main.c.obj -MF CMakeFiles\Practice.dir\main.c.obj.d -o CMakeFiles/Practice.dir/main.c.obj -c C:/.../CLionProjects/Practice/main.c
In file included from C:\...\Programs\Python\Python39\include\pystate.h:143,
                 from C:\...\Programs\Python\Python39\include\genobject.h:11,
                 from C:\...\Programs\Python\Python39\include\Python.h:123,
                 from C:\...\CLionProjects/Practice/main.c:4:
C:\...\Programs\Python\Python39\include\cpython/pystate.h:9:10: fatal error: cpython/initconfig.h: No such file or directory
    9 | #include "cpython/initconfig.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Comment: Why are you including Python.h in your program?

Comment: How are you putting `Python.h` in your program? Show us.

Comment: I don't see any `-I` options in your `gcc` command. That is suspicious. Which include locations are you using?